# creating components at runtime in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, jbutton

All this while i was using visual builder to design.  I want to add some components at runtime. I have added a jpanel at design time.  I want to add a button at run time on jpanel.  This is the generated and the code i have added.  The button is not visible when i run.

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
 */
package main;

import javax.swing.JButton;

 /**
  *
 * @author FirmView
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

private void addGUIComponents(){
    JButton b = new JButton("Click Me");
    jPanel1.add(b);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 341, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 83, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(176, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            NewJFrame f = new NewJFrame();
            f.addGUIComponents();
            f.show();
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: I know why it is not visible, but what is the question? :)

Comment: @matheszabi how to make it visible

Comment: f.addGUIComponents(); f.pack();  f.show(); should solve it, maybe you need contraints too for GroupLayout

Comment: @matheszabi tried, not working

Comment: jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); -will clean all, f.addGUIComponents(); f.pack(); f.show(); - will show only the label => adding the Label at runtime fails because you aren't met the LayoutManager constraints, change the layout, or add constraints

Comment: @matheszabi +1 it works after i changed the layout manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you components like that, you must call `revalidate()` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are **Creating an JPanel object** in `initComponent()` and then **adding button to the another JPanel object** at `addGUIComponents()`

Better make the **JPanel class** a `Singleton`... So you get the **same JPanel object.**

Comment: no, he is adding to the same jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel(); created in initComponents()

Comment: but is the jPanel1 added to his ContentPane?